# rewrite old url to new one

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have this is current url pattern for a group of urls

```
http://www.example.com/assets/img/banner.jpg
```

which will be changing to

```
http://www.example.com/assets/img/all_banners/banner.jpg
```

How do I use `mod_rewrite` to rewrite these urls to the new pattern using .htaccess file?

I have this so far but it is not working...

```
RewriteRule /assets/img/(.*) /assets/img/all_banners/$1 [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
```

Maybe the flags are wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?(assets/img)/([\w-]+\.[a-z]+)$ /$1/all_banners/$2 [R=301,NC,L,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache or use a new browser for testing.